# Spring Cloud with AWS Parameter Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-aws

Is there any integration between Spring Cloud AWS or Spring Cloud Config with AWS Parameter Store?

I just saw this issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/207

But nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I know the issue you've linked was closed with a merged [PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/pull/308) and is now in Spring Cloud [2.0](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_parameter_store), but we had a small lib internally that works with Spring Boot (1.4.x, 1.5.x and 2.0.x) without Spring Cloud if that can help some: https://github.com/coveo/spring-boot-parameter-store-integration. It's on maven central also.